raycasting light beam with loop node
By referencing the infinity laser reflection project (https://windmiller.gumroad.com/l/raycastinglaser), I am currently attempting to recreate it using a loop node. However, it is not functioning properly. It appears to work fine after the first iteration, but starts to go wrong from the second iteration.
The loop:

Inside the loop:



Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

yes! thank you for the link! I added it in the post!

Raycasting with bounces (using margin)
I've restarted from scratch, having a hard time understanding your own setup.
The idea is quite simple. For each point (bounces), compute the hit position, move a point of the mesh accordingly, and update both position and direction of the laser.

So for each bounce, we have the position $\vec{p}$, the direction of the laser $\vec{d}$ and at the hit position, the normal of the surface $\vec{n}$. The blue dot represent the starting point of the current bounce/loop iteration.
1. Base mesh generation
I'm starting with a mesh line, setting the resolution to the number of bounces + 1. Because we are gonna set each point individually, I'm setting all positions to the origin by default.
Additionnaly, we can already set the first point to be at the start of the laser (here Laser head).

2. Repeat zone initialization
The repeat zone have 3 custom fields :

Source location : the starting point of the current laser segment
Source direction : the starting direction of the segment
Iteration : an integer counting our loop number

I'm using two Empty objects to set the position and direction : Laser head and Laser target.

3. Repeat zone process
So we give explicitly the position and direction for the first segment. Then, for each loop (bounce), we compute the Raycast and we get the position of the hit. This position helps us move the current point of the laser.
The new position is a bit tricky. If we just plug the Hit Position to the Source location, a problem arises : our new starting point is inside one face of the cube. Then, the raycast would sometimes work, sometimes not (I believe a side effect of floating point calculation). To be sure to not take into account the current face, on which we just bounced, I'm giving the position a very small margin, based on the normal of current face. Keep in mind that because of it, the laser bounces will be slighty off. Visually unvisible, but still ...
The new direction is easy, just Reflect the direction around the normal.

Note that normals are pointing outwards, and thus we need to invert the normal vector when computing positions and directions.
4. Full node tree

5. Results
Here is an example of use, followed by the blend file.


6. Additionnal informations
I've included in the blend file another setup. The idea was to delete the current face instead of adding a small margin, and so having a perfectly accurate bounce. Sadly, I wasn't able to make it work.

Thank you for setting up the node and explaining the method!
