Repeat zone with raycast issue
I'm  trying to follow this tutorial for creating a ball(s) bouncing inside a cube using geometry nodes. I figured I could go a step further and instead of repeating raycast nodes manually I could use repeat zones (I'm guessing these did not exist at the time of the YT video and so CG Matter did not use them). But I can't get it work and I am not sure what am I missing. Here is my setup and I want to do the following (as described in the YT video)

Raycast to the cube that acts as the boundary by giving an initial ray direction, say (1, 1, 0)
Reflect the ray direction using the normal at the hit position
Raycast again to the cube using the previous hit position as the source position and the reflected ray direction as the new ray direction
Repeat steps 2. and 3. using repeat zone iterations so that I don't have to do it manually.

Here is my setup that works correctly for iteration 1 and then incorrectly for iteration 2 and then stops working.


I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with it, I've answered a similar question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316117/raycasting-light-beam-with-loop-node/316175#316175

Thank you so much. This is very helpful. I wish I could mark this comment as the answer.
